# How to pass a variable to a form radio button in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a form (code below) which takes answers into a response model. Answers are always on a scale of 1-3, but may be referencing a variety of different questions.

`form.py`

```
from Django import forms
RESPONSE_CHOICES = (
   ('1', '1. Happy'),
   ('2', '2. Neutral'),
   ('3', '3. Sad'),
)
class ResponseForm(forms.Form):
    quid = forms.IntegerField()
    response = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RESPONSE_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

`quid` is the foreign key to `ID` in the `question` model.

in `template.html` I have:

```
<form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Is there a way I can set the value of `quid` in the radio buttons of my form template, rendering something like this:

```
    <label>1</label>
    <input type="radio" value="1" name="{{ question.id }}">
    <label>2</label>
    <input type="radio" value="2" name="{{ question.id }}">
    <label>3</label>
    <input type="radio" value="3" name="{{ question.id }}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the form values in the initialisation and do something like this:

```
class ResponseForm(forms.Form):
    quid = forms.IntegerField()
    response = forms.ChoiceField(choices=RESPONSE_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ResponseForm, self).__init__( *args, **kwargs)
        field_value=Question.objects.get(id=kwargs["id"]).response
        self.fields['response'].initial = field_value
```

Note that this assumes you are creating the form with the id parameter.

```
form = ResponseForm(id=quid)#quid is the relevant id
```

You also need to have a plan for an empty form.

However, my recommendations would be:

- use a Foreignkey in your question model instead of the integer id which will make your life easier.
- use a Modelform instead of the Form which will do everything above automated.